# Whic is correct way to use pair GlobalLock() \ GlobalUnlock()?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Documentation about [GlobalLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366584(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> **Return value**
>   If the function succeeds, the return value is a pointer to the first byte of the memory block.
>   **If the function fails**, the **return value is NULL**. To get extended error information, **call GetLastError**.
>
> **Remarks**
>   Each ***successful*** call that a process makes to GlobalLock for an object must be matched by a corresponding call to GlobalUnlock.
>   ....
>   If the specified memory block has been discarded **or if the memory block has a zero-byte size**, this function **returns NULL.**

So, as we see, `GlobalLock()` could return NULL if error or memory block size has zero-byte size.
On the other hand, `GlobalUnlock()` should be called ONLY if `GlobalLock()` was successful. So, how correctly define case when GlobalUnlock() should be called? What approach is correct from following variants and why?

Variant 0:

```
HGLOBAL hMem = /*some handle on global memory block*/;

// lock block
auto pMem = static_cast<LPBYTE>(::GlobalLock(hMem));
if (pMem!=nullptr)
{
   // ... work with pMem

}

// call unlock in any case
::GlobalUnlock(hMem);
```

Variant 1:

```
HGLOBAL hMem = /*some handle on global memory block*/;

// lock block
auto pMem = static_cast<LPBYTE>(::GlobalLock(hMem));
if (pMem!=nullptr)
{
   // ... work with pMem

   // unlock block
   ::GlobalUnlock(hMem);
}
```

Variant 2:

```
HGLOBAL hMem = /*some handle on global memory block*/;

// lock block
auto pMem = static_cast<LPBYTE>(::GlobalLock(hMem));
auto isMemLocked = (pMem!=nullptr);
if (isMemLocked)
{
   // ... work with pMem
}
else
{
   // is it real error?
   isMemLocked = ::GetLastError()==NOERROR;
}

if (isMemLocked)
{
   // unlock block
   ::GlobalUnlock(hMem);
}
```

**Update:**
We assume that hMem is valid (handle is not NULL).

P.S.: Great thanks for your answers.

Comment: @RbMm, thank you, but why not Variant 2? Why do you think that NULL for zero-sized block is not successful call too?

Comment: I'd highly suggest using an RAII wrapper for this. `global_locker` that takes in an `HGLOBAL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [`GlobalLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366584(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation

> Each **successful** call that a process makes to `GlobalLock` for an
>   object must be matched by a corresponding call to `GlobalUnlock`.

and

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a pointer to the first
>   byte of the memory block.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL

so we need call `GlobalUnlock` only if previous call to `GlobalLock` return not `NULL`

pattern is next:

```
    if (PVOID pv = GlobalLock(hg))
    {
        //...
        GlobalUnlock(hg);
    }
```

in case we try do `GlobalLock` on memory block which has a zero-byte size - we always got 0 and `ERROR_DISCARDED`. we not need call `GlobalUnlock` in this case - it simply return `ERROR_NOT_LOCKED` in this case.

---

if look from c++ perspective `GlobalAlloc` with `GMEM_MOVEABLE` flag return ~ [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) - so `HGLOBAL` by fact point to object like [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in this case. the `GlobalLock(hg)` is analog of [`weak_ptr::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) which return [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (direct pointer to actual memory block). and `GlobalLock` is analog of release this [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). after call `GlobalDiscard` on `HGLOBAL hg` - [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (real memory block) will be destroyed. but `HGLOBAL hg` ([`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)) still will be valid, simply every `GlobalLock(hg)` ([`weak_ptr::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock)) call on it fail with error `ERROR_DISCARDED`. finally `GlobalFree`  delete this [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). demo code:

```
if (HGLOBAL hg = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, 8))
{
    if (PVOID pv = GlobalLock(hg))
    {
        ASSERT(!GlobalDiscard(hg));

        GlobalUnlock(hg);
    }

    ASSERT(GlobalDiscard(hg));

    ASSERT(!GlobalLock(hg));

    ASSERT(GetLastError() == ERROR_DISCARDED);

    ASSERT(!GlobalUnlock(hg));

    ASSERT(GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_LOCKED);

    GlobalFree(hg);
}

if (HGLOBAL hg = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, 0))
{
    ASSERT(!GlobalLock(hg));

    ASSERT(GetLastError() == ERROR_DISCARDED);

    ASSERT(!GlobalUnlock(hg));

    ASSERT(GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_LOCKED);

    GlobalFree(hg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (PVOID p = GlobalLock(hGlob))
{
  ...
  GlobalUnlock(hGlob);
}
```

is the correct pattern and answered by RbMm but variant 0 is also accepted by Windows because `GlobalUnlock(NULL)` returns TRUE without doing anything else. This is of course a undocumented implementation detail and I only verified this on Windows NT 4 and Windows 8 but I assume everything in between acts the same.

This happens because Windows uses certain tag bits and [alignment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041109-00/?p=37353/) to tell if the HGLOBAL is fixed or moveable memory and NULL obviously has no tag bits set so `GlobalUnlock` just returns.

There is no reason to use this alternative pattern because:

1. You would be relying on implementation details.
2. You cannot omit the `GlobalLock` return value check unless you know that the HGLOBAL is fixed memory and in that case you can omit all the locking/unlocking because it is pointless overhead if you are only using fixed memory.